# "Call to a member function userList() on a non-object"

Tags: php, oop

I have a custom mvc app which has an index controller and an index model.The url for controllers in this app is $url[0]. The system is designed to redirect to index when the value for controller($url[0] is empty. e.g., When the url is `http://localhost/Test/` The system should automatically redirect to the index.

However, when i include a model method in the controller i get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined property: Index::$model in
>   **Fatal error**: Call to a member function userList() on a non-object

Comment: the reason may be the model is not loaded. to the controller which is causing this issue

Comment: The model is loaded in the controller.

Comment: Where is your custom MVC?. At least you can add controller model script in question.

Comment: how do you mean @Adnanhaider?

Comment: Add model controller code in question.

Comment: see edited question

Comment: Any suggestion to resolving this error @Adnanhaider

Comment: model is controller class variable, some how it is not instantiated. Share your complete code not functions. Let me know the point where you are loading model.

Comment: @Adnanhaider please see the revised question

Comment: Add this require "index_model.php"; before your index controller. if still doesn't let me know i will write the answer.

Comment: This does not work and instead halts the index method from running.

Comment: For your index controller model is not loaded before you call its function.

Comment: Create the git repository and share the complete MVC code.I will debug it.

Comment: I have given up. I have changed my design

Comment: @tapeli oh , ok  so without complete information this question is useless delete it.

Comment: @Adnanhaider i had provided you with the complete code. I cannot delete this question. I am still hoping i will get an answer as to why the code works when the controller is not empty but doesn't work when the controller is empty

Comment: @tapeli Everyone is here helping each other. Just share your complete code. i will implement it on my localhost without error. 
Currently your provided code shows logical error in bootstrap class. You default controller load but default model is not loading.

Comment: @tapeli great. I will check it and get back to you soon.

Comment: not able to chat because i have less than 20 points reputation

Comment: @Adnanhaider any success?

Comment: @Adnanhaider see my answer below. One of the ways to avoid the error is redirecting the header to index controller because the  $controller->Index() on bootstrap.php overrides the method Index() in the Index controller and hence not allowing the model to be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the bootstrap.php file line 21 to line 27. You say that when the url is http://localhost/Test/index the app works as expected but when $url[0] is empty i.e., http://localhost/Test you get the error after explicitly stating that if url[0] is empty then the system should automatically redirect to index controller. Try amending your bootstrap by introducing more logic

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have looked at the logic in lines 21 to 27  as you have  suggested and think that i should not tamper with it since it works well. I highly suspect that my design is faulty and that index controllers were never meant to display data in PHP

Answer (score 0):

After much deliberation and thinking, i figured that the only way to avoid this error is to change one line on bootstrap.php. i replaced the `$Controller->Index()`; with a header location call like this `header('Location: ' . index)`. This is due to the fact that setting the controller to `$controller->Index()` in the bootstrap overrides the Index action/method defined in the index controller(index.php) hence stopping the controller from loading the model.

This way the page will always redirect to `http://localhost/Test/index` when the `url[0]` is empty.